# How to format output to DD, HH, MM

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to work out a devices up time using PowerShell. My code is as so:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$upTime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LocalDateTime) – $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
```

When I call $upTime, it returns the following:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 1
Minutes           : 8
Seconds           : 5
Milliseconds      : 311
Ticks             : 40853110010
TotalDays         : 0.0472836921412037
TotalHours        : 1.13480861138889
TotalMinutes      : 68.0885166833333
TotalSeconds      : 4085.311001
TotalMilliseconds : 4085311.001
```

While I can see the up time, I need to specifically format the output to **D:dd, H:hh, M:mm** as I will be automatically feeding this into a monitoring system, but after much searching on here, google etc, I can't see how to achieve this. Can anyone suggest how to go about doing this?

Comment: Please show us an example of the desired output from you example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"D:{0:dd}, H:{0:hh}, M:{0:mm}" -f $upTime
```

alternatively, if you like to escape lots of things:

```
$upTime.ToString('\D\:dd\,\ \H\:hh\,\ \M\:mm')
```

This will format the string to have 2 leading zeros when ether days, hours or seconds is 0. And 1 leading zero if they are 1-9.

```
"D:01, H:02, M:23"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that is exactly what I'm after. :)

Comment: I did try but had to wait a minute, now accepted. :)

Comment: I took the liberty of drastically simplifying your code; you didn't know how format strings actually work, perhaps.

Comment: Cheers @Joey I was looking for a way to have it in one string. Didn't know about the `:` string formatting operator.

Answer (score -1):

You can format it in normal .NET style

```
$UptimeStr = $Uptime.ToString("ddd:dd, H:hh, mmm:mm")
```

or

```
$UptimeStr = '{0:ddd:dd, H:hh, mmm:mm}' -f $Uptime
```

If the above formatting is not what you wanted the formatting is explained on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Exception calling "ToString" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format." You really have to escape a lot to make that work (see my edits to Richard's answer).